# Active Directory Subdomain vs new "Tree in Forest" ... is there a difference?

Tags: domain, subdomain, domain-controller, active-directory

We have the forest named "company.com" and are debating between "thing.company.com" versus "thing.local".  My understanding is that the latter is called a "Tree in a Forest"

What are the deciding criteria that will help me choose which is better?  Is there any security, management, or GPO setting that favors one over the other?

Comment: Correct, the latter choice would constitute a new tree in the forest (unless you create a new forest). What is the motivation behind an additional domain?

Comment: Don't use .local or any other made up TLD!

Comment: @Jessen The motivation is to support CA Siteminder / Arcott which needs to separate LDAP accounts by "LDAP Containers" (something the Dev says).  It is also to migrate features off of ADAM

Comment: Why not use OUs in that case? OUs are "separate" containers by most accounts.

Comment: @Dave Agreed, I'm creating an argument for this purpose, but it may be an internal fight not worth having.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real difference other than the DNS namespace will be disjoint. The first domain (i.e. company.com) will remain as the forest root domain.

Comment: Do any policies inherit? (GPO or otherwise)

Comment: GPOs do not inherit between domains in a forest regardless of whether their DNS namespace is contiguous or not. Domains are a security boundary.

Comment: Not trying to troll, but Microsoft and NIST documentation both state that domains are not a security boundary, but that forests are.

Comment: @SamErde Good catch, my bad!